# Bootstrap 4.0 invalid-feedback doesn't show

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using the Bootstrap 4.0 (non-beta) validation and have a problem to display the invalid-feedback text.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <label class="form-control-label">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control is-invalid" min="0" type="number"/>
  </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Invalid Feedback Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example the text "Invalid Feedback Text" is not displayed.

The reason for it is that the invalid-feedback div is not a direct sibling of the the input control.

This has been an issue with the alpha/beta versions however I was under the impression that this has been fixed in the 4.0 release.  (At least the relevant [ticket](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454) has been closed.)

So, how can I use the bootstrap validation if I can not have the feedback text as a direct sibling of the relevant input control? (It is simply not feasible in my application.)

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zygrsrox/

Comment: Why not put it as a direct sibling then?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in it in a `form` tag ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're right, the intention is that the input is a sibling of the feedback message. The only way you can force the invalid-feeback to show is to use something like `d-block` (or some custom CSS selector). Perhaps you can add `d-block` programatically in your app during validation.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <label class="form-control-label">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control is-invalid" min="0" type="number"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
    Invalid Feedback Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is d-block? I had the similar issue but in mine case, error validation has its own component and adding d-block class inside the component did the trick but i have no idea why and what is d-block?

Comment: `display:block` Check out [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#notation)

Comment: Thanks for this @Zim.  New to Laravel and struggling with this and this d-block helped me now in 2022