# Bootstrap 4 and form-control-feedback using icons

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, form-control

I want to use the form-control feedback styling in bootstrap 4 but I cannot get the desired display.
The idea is to show an icon inside the input field and an error message.

I am using `Angular 5.2.9`, `bootstrap 4` and `fontawesome` icons.

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group"
         [ngClass]="{'has-error has-feedback' : form.get('Title').errors?.required }">
        <label for="title">Quiz title:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="title"
               formControlName="Title"
               placeholder="choose a title..."
               class="form-control" />
        <span *ngIf="form.get('Title').errors?.required"
              class="fa fa-eraser form-control invalid-feedback"
              aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        <div *ngIf="(form.get('Title').dirty
                 || form.get('Title').touched)
                 && form.get('Title').errors?.required"
             class="text-danger">
            <small>
                Title is required field: please insert a valid title
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**result**

[image]

If I change the `text-danger` for `invalid-feedback` then the div with the message is not displayed at all because of the css property `display: none;`

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to achieve the following?
[image]

*Edit*

this solution [Bootstrap 4.0 (non-beta) .invalid-feedback doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401656/bootstrap-4-0-non-beta-invalid-feedback-doesnt-show?rq=1)  using `d-block` for the div does the trick for the error message. Still need to figure out how to put the fontawesome icon inside the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.fa-eraser {
  width: 15px;
  margin: -25px 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

set exact with on your fa icon right now you set the ico the same size as span text..

[CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKwxRR)